# How do I sort an array based on another array's IDs?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays.The first array have an IDs of rows which matches certain rules.
Please note that I do not have access to the SQL server for running queries.

```
$ids = array (
  0 => '13',
  1 => '14',
  2 => '12',
  3 => '83'
);


$groups = array (
  0 => 
  array (
      'id' => '83',
      'email' => 'joe'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '12',
    'name' => 'emily'
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '13',
    'name' => 'leo'
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '14',
    'name' => 'jack'
  )
);
```

I want the second array to be sorted according to the IDs in the first array.The expected result is this :

```
$groups = array (
  0 => 
  array (
      'id' => '13',
      'email' => 'leo'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '14',
    'name' => 'jack'
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '12',
    'name' => 'emily'
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '83',
    'name' => 'joe'
  )
);
```

Could you guys help me?

thanks!

Comment: just use `foreach` the loop the ids first inside it the groups, push inside if found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$flippedIds = array_flip($ids);

$result = array();

foreach ($group as $item) {
   $result[$flippedIds[$item['id']]] = $item;
}
```

This is given your $ids are unique.

Also you might need to throw in a

```
ksort($result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code creating $groups, then

```
$flippedIds = array_flip($ids);
$group[flippedIds[$id]] = array($id,$name);
ksort($group);
```

Otherwise you could

```
$flippedIds = array_flip($ids);
foreach $group as $k => $val){
  $group[$k] = $group[$flippedIds[$val['id']]][$k][$val];
}
ksort($group);
```

If the $group array will never have a duplicate id from $ids then the [$k] element can be removed.  Otherwise the duplicated values will over write the previous.

```
$flippedIds = array_flip($ids);
foreach $group as $k => $val){
  $group[$k] = $group[$flippedIds[$val['id']]][$val];
}
ksort($group);
```

Comment: What i'm saying is that inside for loop your $value is an array right? 
Like this array('id' => '13', 'name' => 'leo') and your trying to access the id with $value[0].  There is no $value[0], there is only $value['id'] and $value['name']

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: punker@ubuntu:~$ php -r '$arr = array("id" => '1'); echo $arr[0];'
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in Command line code on line 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69638/discussion-between-misunderstood-and-mikewu).

Comment: It should be working. Have you tried it? Is this what you are looking for?  I do not know what you want to do with the data after it is in a sorted array, so there is not much else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$newArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++)
{       
    $groupKey = recursive_array_search($ids[$i],$groups);
    $newArray[] = $groups[$groupKey];        
}

print_r($newArray);
```